# Ruby Rack Heroku: No CSS styling when serving a static site

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've been attempting to deploy a static site of HTML, CSS, font, and image files with Ruby Rack (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby). I'm running it locally and the site's HTML displays in Chrome but CSS assets don't seem to be loading and applied to the HTML. Nor do images appear.

I've been focusing on `config.ru` but this might not be the issue:

```
  use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/fonts", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

  run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

I've used both the WEBrick and Thin servers and there's almost no difference in result (Thin will serve SVGs).

My directory structure looks like this (there's a link to `fees.html` from within `index.html` but when I click on this "fees.html" link, the `fees.html` doesn't load - `index.html` is displayed instead):

```
- site
  |- config.ru
  |- Gemfile
  |- Gemfile.lock
  |- public
    |- index.html
    |- fees.html
    |- css
    |- fonts
    |- images
```

**Question**: Although I've used Heroku to deploy apps in the past, I'm new to deploying static sites. Should I change something in `config.ru` or might the issue lurk elsewhere?

**EDIT** I should mention that the site itself displays correctly (styling correctly applied, all assets included) when I open it in Chrome without using Ruby Rack.

**EDIT 2** `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <main>
        <section class="tech" id="nextsection">
          <div class="tech-row">
            <div class="tech-column">
              <img src="images/red_icon.svg" alt="Your Cash">
              <h4>Your Cash</h4>
              <p>Seed your retirement with recurring payments</p>
            </div>
           </div>
       </section>
      </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 3** Here's the [repo with code](https://github.com/orlando21/everwealth). When I download and open locally in Chrome, it displays correctly.

Comment: Please show snippets of index.html where you import the css and use the images.

Comment: Not enough information. But I'm wondering, if the storage site has a "public" subdirectory (i.e. the dir that faces the web), do the files in other subdirectories actually work?

Comment: Have you precompiled the assets?

Comment: I added the code repo under "edit 3" above. Nothing's precompiled - just plain ole' html/css/js. So I included a "public" subdirectory but only for the purposes of Ruby Rack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `config/production.rb`. You can alternatively add Heroku's `rails_12factor` gem which does this for you, among other things.

Comment: Thanks - this worked after additionally clearing my browser cache.

Comment: btw if you don't mind me asking... where does this `config/production.rb` actually live? (I got it to work by installing the `rails_12factor` gem and not setting the flag in `production.rb`).

Comment: There is a file at `config/production.rb` in the rails app.

Comment: If I'm just serving a bunch of static files locally [via Rack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby), what would be the rails app in this case?

Comment: Oh I guess I didn't read your question in enough detail to realize you weren't using Rails, my bad. I really have no idea and it's news to me that rails_12factor even works outside rails.